# ASP.Net Core Razor with Blazor WASM and Wildcard URL

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-routing

I'm creating a website with a Blazor WASM as the admin, and a Core Razor is the main site. I didnt have any problem so far mixing both, but on the main site I have a Wildcar url, that gets anything "/{*url}" if I enable it the Blazor stop working, it is possible to do it?
Here is my Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dynamic/index", "{*url}");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
else
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToFile("admin/{*path:nonfile}", "admin/index.html");

app.Run();
```

thanks

Comment: Do you wanna all the url will route the `/Dynamic/index` Page? What does `Blazor stop working` mean?  Does the page show something like `Sorry, there's nothing at this address`

Comment: I do have some static pages, like calendar, events, etc, but also it will have some dynamic pages that will be route to /dynamic/index, I used :
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dynamic/index", "{*url}");
and it worked fine, but then my admin that is in blazor stop working once i add this line, is there any way to have an if, like if the url is ="/admin" i will skip the wildcard option?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. this is my code in case someone has the same problem:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Dynamic/index", "{*url}");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
else
{
    //add for blazor client
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

//add blazor
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();

app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/admin"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.Use((context, nxt) =>
    {
        context.Request.Path = "/admin" + context.Request.Path;
        return nxt();
    });

    appBuilder.UseStaticFiles();
    appBuilder.UseRouting();

    appBuilder.UseAuthentication();
    appBuilder.UseAuthorization();

    appBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("admin/{*path:nonfile}", "admin/index.html");
    });
});

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```